# Is it possible to determine of a Java Class object is the same across VMs

Tags: java, class, identification

I have many instances of a particular programs running on different machines.  Except for downtime to install a new version, the program is running all the time, and during installations, different versions of the program can be running on different machines.  But since there are so many different installation I'd like to make sure that data (effectively) serialized from one definition of a class from a particular running producer of the class's is the same as the class definition of the receiver of the data.

So the obvious solution would be to use a serialVerionUID but changing that breaks other stuff and people can forget to update the ID between, and that is not available from the class object itself (object.getClass()).  System.identityHashcode() is of no value as well.

So I guess the real question if someone hands you a Class object and you have reference to the expected class object, is there a way to tell if both classes represent the same thing *exactly*, fields, field definitions, etc. even if the class has exactly the same package and name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to preserve object identity across different VMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994113/how-to-preserve-object-identity-across-different-vms)

Comment: In this case all that's available is the Class object and not an instance of the/a class

Comment: The answer is not to use Java serialization for this, but a protocol that explicitly supports forwards compatibility - for example Protobuf, Avro, FlatBuffers etc

Answer (score 1):

You could compare the `hashCode()` of the bytes in the `.class` file for the class, which you know is available because the class loaded.

Here's some code to get the hash:

```
public static int getHash(Class<?> clazz) throws IOException {
    return Arrays.hashCode(clazz.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(clazz.getName().replace(".", "/")).readAllBytes());
}
```

Comment: I wonder what sorts of changes influence the hash - for example, would refactoring to rearrange field declaration order change the hash? Seems like it would end up with the same problems as not declaring a `serialVerionUID`.

Comment: @Boris exceedingly unlikely. The hash is byte-order dependant, like `String#hashCode()`. It's not a checksum.

Comment: My understanding is that hashcode() is a number related to the _contents_ of a class, not the _definition_ of the class.  So all a hashcode would do is to make sure that the contents of two instances are the same.  Am I correct?  The goal is to make sure the class _definition_ is the same when two classes of the same name are compared.

Comment: @allan you are not correct. This code compares the hashcode of the bytecode (the “definition”) of the class. You could pass this hashcode over the wire and compare it at the other end. When you used the phrase “*contents* of the class” I think you mean “contents of the *instance* of the class”, which is the usual purpose of hashcode. In this case, the “instance” is a `byte[]` that contains your class’s definition.

Comment: @Bohemian I think you are incorrect.  For example, lets assume I have two String objects, one containing "A" and the other "B".  The hashcode for each is different but the definition is the same.  The hashcode is based upon the _contents_ of an instance, not the _definition_ of the instance.

Comment: @allan if you read the question carefully, OP wants to assert that the *class* definition is the same across all JVMs. Quoting OP: ***I'd like to make sure** that data (effectively) serialized from one definition of a class from a particular running **producer of the class's is the same as the class definition of the receiver** of the data*

Comment: @Bohemian Indeed you are correct.  getHash() above is hashing the Class definition, not the instance.  I stand corrected.  This function should work well.

Answer (score 0):

You can. But it has its downsides, you can use reflection to check all properties, methods and internals of your object and compare it to another object to check for equivalence.

```
Class c = ob.getClass();
for (Method method : c.getMethods()) {
  if (method.getAnnotation(PostConstruct.class) != null) {
    System.out.println(method.getName());
  }
}
```

Thats for methods.

And you can do the same for fields:

```
Field[] allFields = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

Then you can check if they are the same version of a class or not. If the difference is in number of methods or fields, however if the change is inside of a method you can't easily tell una class from the other.

Comment: If the version of the class can be deserialized, then there is no reason to check if it's the same. If the version of the class cannot be deserialized then you cannot check if it's the same. Not sure your suggestion is overly useful...

Comment: @Camilo Your code will indeed work but is very expensive to do since it involves reflection.  I may end up having to use your method anyway.

Comment: @BoristheSpider In my case what is being sent across the wire is the class and not an instance of a class.  But your suggestion is still good.